# Mutex in C++, global variable or privately defined inside each class?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I came over two approachs when trying to access from multiple threads to a shared instance of a class in C++:

1) Access the object instance passed by reference from the thread using a global mutex by calling lock_guard.

2) Create a mutex as a private variable in the class, and calling inside each member of that class lock_guard when trying to access concurrently some variable in the class.

So, which method is more suitable and why?

Comment: Both do different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel more comfortable using mutex as members.

- Basically the mutex belongs to the resource, which it secures multiple access to. As the resource belongs to the class, so does the protecting mutex. So it is much more suitable to use the mutex as private member an in order a private lock function.
- Additional I would suggest to NEVER use global variables, except you have a really really good reason and though about it really long.

Comment: So, you should lock the variables that may be accessed concurrently instead the object instance itself, right? For example, should I encounter any concurrency problem if I do std::cout << &bar << std::endl from multiple threads, where bar is a pointer to an object instance?

Comment: If I understand you correct, yes. You should lock just, what is a problem accessing concurrent. The object itself may be not the problem for concurrency. In many cases only the member variables are the problem. You want to have a secure access. That is what I can say, not knowing your problem =)

Answer (score 0):

I was about to say emphatically #2 (mutex as member of class).  But then had a moment to reflect.

**They are both viable and have their purposes.**

Option 1 is basically saying that instances of a class are not thread safe and requires threads to synchronize access.  Such is the case with most C++ collection classes in the std:: namespace (e.g. vector, map, etc…)

Option 2 is basically saying, "instances of this class are thread safe".

I personally prefer #1 for classes that represent data objects (e.g. "Point", "Matrix" "ApplicationSettings", or any class with member functions that are getter/setters). Or which have a lifetime managed by some other class.  Or, if the primary intent is that the class instance is only going to be used by a single thread a time.  Or put it another way, simple classes.

Option #2 (mutex as member) is when class objects are offering a service with an intent towards being useful for multiple (possibly **unrelated**) threads at a time.  For example, a database, logging service, or message queue object that exists for the entire application.  Or when the object is going to receive messages from another object on another thread.